# python3 epoch from timestamp string

Tags: python, python-3.x, datetime, numpy, timestamp

I have this type of timestamp:

```
'Mon Oct 31 2016 23:00:00 GMT+0000 (UTC)'
```

Mode code to Convert to unix from str (not working):

```
def str2timestamp(self,timestr,epoch=datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp(0)):
    timestr = timestr.replace('GMT+0000 (UTC)', '').strip()

    dt = datetime.datetime.strptime(timestr.strip(), '%a %b %d %Y %H:%M:%S')
    return (dt - epoch).total_seconds()
```

I get this error:

> ValueError: time data "b'Mon Oct 31 2016 23:00:00 '" does not match format '%a %b %d %Y %H:%M:%S

I call it from numpy converter to convert a timestamp column to epoch-number.

```
self.dataset = loadtxt("data/dataset.csv", delimiter=",",converters={0: lambda d: self.str2timestamp(str(d))})
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a bit simpler implementation, that does what you need:

**Code:**

```
import datetime as dt

def str2timestamp(timestr, epoch=dt.datetime.fromtimestamp(0)):
    stamp = dt.datetime.strptime(timestr.strip()[4:24], '%b %d %Y %H:%M:%S')
    return (stamp - epoch).total_seconds()
```

**Test Code:**

```
print(str2timestamp('Mon Oct 31 2016 23:00:00 GMT+0000 (UTC)'))
```

**Results:**

```
1477983600.0
```